# Insertar Meses Faltantes

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, .net

Tengo mi tabla Abonos a la cual necesito hacer una consulta para que me devuelva los subtotales por mes y el total general, solo que al consultar debo tomar el rango de fechas del primer registro y el ultimo y rellenar dentro de ese rango los meses faltantes.

En este caso faltaría:

- 2019-03-01
- 2019-05-01
- 2019-06-01
- 2019-08-01

Tabla:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Abonos](
    [IdAbono] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Fecha] [datetime] NULL,
    [Periodo] [int] NULL,
    [Concepto] [nvarchar](100) NULL,
    [FormaPago] [nvarchar](100) NULL,
    [Cargo] [decimal](18, 2) NULL,
    [Abono] [decimal](18, 2) NULL,
    [Mensaje] [nvarchar](40) NULL)

insert into Abonos values('2019-01-01 00:00:00.000',    0,  CONCEPTO,   EFECTIVO,   0.00,   10000.00,   '');
insert into Abonos values('2019-01-01 00:00:00.000',    0,  CONCEPTO,   EFECTIVO,   0.00,   10000.00,   '');
insert into Abonos values('2019-02-01 00:00:00.000',    0,  CONCEPTO,   EFECTIVO,   0.00,   10000.00,   '');
insert into Abonos values('2019-04-01 00:00:00.000',    0,  CONCEPTO,   EFECTIVO,   0.00,   10000.00,   '');
insert into Abonos values('2019-07-01 00:00:00.000',    0,  CONCEPTO,   EFECTIVO,   0.00,   10000.00,   '');
insert into Abonos values('2019-09-01 00:00:00.000',    0,  CONCEPTO,   EFECTIVO,   0.00,   10000.00,   '');
```

Consulta:

```
select IdAbono, year(Fecha) as Año, month(Fecha) as Mes,day(Fecha)as Día,
Periodo, Concepto, FormaPago,sum(Abono) as Abono, Mensaje            
from Abonos       
group by grouping sets (            
(IdAbono,
year(Fecha),month(Fecha),day(Fecha),Periodo,Concepto,FormaPago,Mensaje),            
(year(Fecha),month(Fecha)),            
()            
)            
;
```

En SQL no se me ocurre como hacerlo, si sirve de algo estoy ocupando C#.

Comment: Se me ocurre que por SQL podrías hacer la operación mediante un sp, obteniendo los meses ingresados con un distinct y agregando los que deseas. Ahora eso sería mucho más fácil si lo haces por C#

Comment: ¿Qué datos irían en dichos meses faltantes? Por ejemplo, para la fecha 2019-03-01 que datos irian en período, concepto, forma de pago, cargo, abono, etc?

Comment: irían los mismos,
insert into Abonos values('2019-03-01 00:00:00.000',    0,  CONCEPTO,   EFECTIVO,   0.00,   10000.00,   '');

Answer (score 0):

Puedes crear *al vuelo* una *tabla* donde estén todos los meses que hay en el período de fechas de tu interés y luego utilizar esta *tabla* para crear, también *al vuelo*, los registros de *abonos* faltantes para estos meses.

Vamos por partes, si declaramos `@fechaIni` y `@fechaFin`, podemos crear un CTE de los meses entre estas fechas de esta manera:

```
declare @fechaIni date = '20190101'
      , @fechafin date = '20190731';

declare @fAuxIni date = eomonth(@fechaIni)
      , @fAuxFin date = eomonth(@fechaFin);
declare @numMeses int = datediff(month, @fAuxIni, @fAuxFin);

with
Contador as (
select n - 1 n
  from (select row_number() over (order by (select null)) n from sys.columns) a
 where n <= @numMeses + 1
)
,
Mes as (
select   year(dateadd(month, Contador.n, @FechaIni)) Anio
       , month(dateadd(month, Contador.n, @FechaIni)) Mes
       , cast(  cast(year(dateadd(month, Contador.n, @FechaIni)) as varchar(4)) 
              + case when month(dateadd(month, Contador.n, @FechaIni)) < 10 then '0' else '' end
              + cast(month(dateadd(month, Contador.n, @FechaIni)) as varchar(2))
              + '01'
              as date) InicioDeMes
       , eomonth(dateadd(month, Contador.n, @FechaIni)) FinDeMes
  from Contador
)
```

La idea es:

- Encontramos la fecha de fin de mes de cada una de las fechas dadas (por lo que entiendo, solo procesaremos meses completos).
- Contamos el número de meses que hay entre ambas fechas
- Con este dato, generamos un CTE con un consecutivo que va de `0`, `1`, `2`, hasta `n-2`, `n-1`, donde `n` es el número de meses que hay entre ambas fechas.
- Finalmente, generamos una CTE `Mes` que tiene el año, mes, fecha de inicio y fecha de fin de cada uno de los meses que hay en el rango de fechas. Para cada mes, nos basamos en la fecha de inicio y le vamos sumando el consecutivo `n` del CTE anterior.

Finalmente, con estos datos, podemos fácilmente determinar los meses para los que no hay ningún registro de abono:

```
select Mes.InicioDeMes
  from Mes
 where not exists (select 1 from Abonos where Abonos.Fecha between Mes.InicioDeMes and Mes.FinDeMes)
```

Si ponemos todas las piezas juntas, nos quedaría algo como esto (nótese que estoy simulando la tabla de `Abonos` también con un CTE:

```
declare @fechaIni date = '20190101'
      , @fechafin date = '20190731';

declare @fAuxIni date = eomonth(@fechaIni)
      , @fAuxFin date = eomonth(@fechaFin);
declare @numMeses int = datediff(month, @fAuxIni, @fAuxFin);

with
Abonos as (
select *
  from (values (1, cast('20190101' as date), 0, 'concepto', 'efectivo', cast(0.0 as money), cast(10000.0 as money), '')
             , (2, '20190101', 0, 'concepto', 'efectivo', 0.0, 10000.0, '')
             , (3, '20190201', 0, 'concepto', 'efectivo', 0.0, 10000.0, '')
             , (4, '20190401', 0, 'concepto', 'efectivo', 0.0, 10000.0, '')
             , (5, '20190701', 0, 'concepto', 'efectivo', 0.0, 10000.0, '')
             , (6, '20190901', 0, 'concepto', 'efectivo', 0.0, 10000.0, '')
       ) q (idAbono, Fecha, Periodo, Concepto, FormaPago, Cargo, Abono, Mensaje)
)
,
Contador as (
select n - 1 n
  from (select row_number() over (order by (select null)) n from sys.columns) a
 where n <= @numMeses + 1
)
,
Mes as (
select   year(dateadd(month, Contador.n, @FechaIni)) Anio
       , month(dateadd(month, Contador.n, @FechaIni)) Mes
       , cast(  cast(year(dateadd(month, Contador.n, @FechaIni)) as varchar(4)) 
              + case when month(dateadd(month, Contador.n, @FechaIni)) < 10 then '0' else '' end
              + cast(month(dateadd(month, Contador.n, @FechaIni)) as varchar(2))
              + '01'
              as date) InicioDeMes
       , eomonth(dateadd(month, Contador.n, @FechaIni)) FinDeMes
  from Contador
)
,
MesesFaltantes as (
select Mes.InicioDeMes
  from Mes
 where not exists (select 1 from Abonos where Abonos.Fecha between Mes.InicioDeMes and Mes.FinDeMes)
)
,
AbonosExtendidos as (
select Abonos.*
  from Abonos
 where Abonos.Fecha between @fAuxIni and @fAuxFin
union all 
select   null idAbono
       , MesesFaltantes.InicioDeMes Fecha
       , null Periodo
       , null Concepto
       , null FormaPago
       , null Cargo
       , null Abono
       , null Mensaje
  from MesesFaltantes
)
select   Year(fecha) as Año
       , month(fecha) as mes
       , idAbono
       , day(fecha) as dia
       , Periodo
       , concepto
       , FormaPago
       , coalesce(sum(Abono), 0) as Abono
       , Mensaje 
  from AbonosExtendidos
 group by grouping sets (
     (idAbono, year(fecha), month(fecha), day(fecha), Periodo, concepto, FormaPago, Mensaje)
   ,  (year(fecha), month(fecha))
   ,  ()
 );
```

Que nos devuelve el siguiente resultado:

```
Año         mes         idAbono     dia         Periodo     concepto FormaPago Abono                                   Mensaje
----------- ----------- ----------- ----------- ----------- -------- --------- --------------------------------------- -------
2019        2           3           1           0           concepto efectivo  10000.0000                              
2019        2           NULL        NULL        NULL        NULL     NULL      10000.0000                              NULL
2019        3           NULL        1           NULL        NULL     NULL      0.0000                                  NULL
2019        3           NULL        NULL        NULL        NULL     NULL      0.0000                                  NULL
2019        4           4           1           0           concepto efectivo  10000.0000                              
2019        4           NULL        NULL        NULL        NULL     NULL      10000.0000                              NULL
2019        5           NULL        1           NULL        NULL     NULL      0.0000                                  NULL
2019        5           NULL        NULL        NULL        NULL     NULL      0.0000                                  NULL
2019        6           NULL        1           NULL        NULL     NULL      0.0000                                  NULL
2019        6           NULL        NULL        NULL        NULL     NULL      0.0000                                  NULL
2019        7           5           1           0           concepto efectivo  10000.0000                              
2019        7           NULL        NULL        NULL        NULL     NULL      10000.0000                              NULL
NULL        NULL        NULL        NULL        NULL        NULL     NULL      30000.0000                              NULL
Warning: Null value is eliminated by an aggregate or other SET operation.

(13 rows affected)
```